# get Latest session value in Javascript

Tags: javascript

and using JavaScript Validation,
I am unable to submit my form because JavaScript session variable is getting one step previous value,
while onother hand user is Seeing new Captcha value,
how can I get rid of this,
I am using

```
<script>
var voo = ("<?php echo $_SESSION['captcha'];?>");
alert(voo);
</script>
```

I am working online,
Here is the live demo that i am facing,
http://imperialsoft.com.pk/dwriters/submit-your-work/

Comment: @AndrewThompson Dear please go the live link, and Click on Submit,
plz help me,\

Comment: @AndrewThompson You can put carpet in cars and JS in Java. Your analogy is flawless from all angles, good sir.

Comment: *"please go the live link"*  No.  Many people will not click on external links, and you should provide a text summary of what the point of visiting the link is.

Comment: @SKP i see woodworm in the alert so what do i do?

Comment: @AnshumanDwibhashi Dear this is the problem that it alert is showing 1 step previous value

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is clientside and session is on the server. So,
set your session variable value in server side, and then use that session variable to retrieve the value in javascript.

or

You could write some javascript on the server-side and put the session variable in it and the render the result to your page.

Hope this helps,
Thanks.

Comment: Dear plz guide me how I can do this

Comment: in your controller/handler class declare your session variable and set value to that variable as Session["myVariable"]="abc" and then use that variable in the javascript. or in another way you can declare a hidden field in your page and then assign your session value to that field. You can retrieve your value from that field using javascript.

Comment: Dear How Can I use Hidden Field Method?
So that I can get rid of this thing,
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20772428/html-store-session-value-in-hidden-input-field

Comment: i am not a php guy, so i am not sure about the syntax on php :)