# How can I put the session variable in a hidden field using the Wordpress editor?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I want to save my Session Variable value in html Hidden Input Field using wordpress editor. Here is my hidden field:

```
<input type="hidden" id="flv" name="flv" value="??"/>
```

What should I pass in

```
value=""
```

so that I can get Session Variable Value,
In PHP My session Variable is

```
$_SESSION['captcha'];
```

Comment: Why would you want a session var in a form? Since it's in a cookie, it's sent to the server every time. I'm sure Wordpress can read the session when necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Just echo it out inside the value:

```
<input type="hidden" id="flv" name="flv" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['captcha]; ?>"/>
```

**UPDATE**

Since the wordpress part wasn't specified anywhere in your question

If you are thinking of doing it directly through wordpress editor then I am afraid, you won't be able to do so directly. You may use some shortcode in order to achieve that.

Here is the link to get you started with:

http://www.sitepoint.com/create-custom-shortcodes-for-wordpress-in-two-minutes/

Comment: I am using this Hidden Field Code in Wordpress Editor, and there PHP does not work,